# How to extract distinct rows in excel?

Tags: excel

I am attempting to reduce an existing array of cells into a list of the distinct rows.  For example, I would like to take an array like this:

```
Ripe  Fruit
Yes   Apple
Yes   Apple
No    Apple
No    Apple
No    Apple
Yes   Orange
Yes   Orange
No    Pear
```

And reduce it down into this:

```
Ripe  Fruit
Yes   Apple
No    Apple
Yes   Orange
No    Pear
```

Such that only one copy of each distinct row exists in the new array.

Thus far I have tried to use a mix of the index, countifs, and the small functions, but haven't been able to produce the result I am looking for.

Edit: I apologize for not clarifying this earlier, but this is part of a system I am trying to build to automate some work.  Thus, remove duplicates, while being an excellent one off solution, doesn't suit my needs here.

As per requests here are some of the solutions I've attempted:

The first thing I attempted was to do Countifs such as 'Countifs(A1:A8, A1, B1:B8, B1) which would yield the new column:

```
Ripe  Fruit   Countif
Yes   Apple   2
Yes   Apple   2
No    Apple   3
No    Apple   3
No    Apple   3
Yes   Orange  2
Yes   Orange  2
No    Pear    1
```

From there I was debating using the small function in some way, but I ran into an issue where if two distinct rows had the same number of results then the function would not work, so I scrapped the idea.

My next thought was slightly more obtuse; I thought that it might work to convert each of the distinct rows to a number somehow, but I haven't developed the thought experiment much beyond that.

Comment: Excel has `Remove Duplicates` it is on the data tab.

Comment: I would use remove duplicates, but I need this to be part of a larger automated process.

Comment: You can remove duplicates with VBA, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: *I need this to be part of a larger automated process* you mean a VBA macro? because the question is not tagged as VBA. Do you nead an VBA solution?

Comment: Please include the code you tried so far to achieve this through VBA, as of right now the answer below does what you want!

Comment: I've been trying to keep this within the realm of base excel funtions so I haven't attempted this yet in VBA. Not tagging this question as VBA was intentional because of that. While I'm not opposed to using VBA if necessary I would prefer to stick with base excel functions.

Comment: So with that you say you want to do this through formulas? In that case, please include your attempted formulas. You might be closer to an answer than you think. :)

Comment: What about using Pivot Tables ? May that work for whatever you need to do later on? Maybe if you post what are you trying to achieve, you can find a solution

Comment: Also, if you got Excel 365, you can use Function [UNIQUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e)

Comment: I didn't know about the UNIQUE function! I do have 365 but for some reason the UNIQUE function is not coming up, I am looking into this issue now.  Thank you very much for pointing this out to me I think this is exactly what I am looking for!

Edit: Oh I see, the UNIQUE function is only available for office insiders as of right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect somewhere out there is a more efficient formula, but for now that's all I could develop so... here it goes...

You'd need to introduce a "helper" column that joins both texts using some unique delimiter, e.g. `=TEXTJOIN("||",,A2:B2)`

[image]

The next step is to have the following Array function (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) in column G - this will show you the unique values from column C:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$9,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$C$1:$C$9),0)),"")
```

[image]

Now the job is easy - add `=IF(LEN(G2),LEFT(G2,FIND("||",G2)-1),"")` to column E and `=IF(LEN(G2),RIGHT(G2,LEN(G2)-FIND("||",G2)-1),"")` to column F:

[image]

You can hide columns C & G for the presentation purposes.

Comment: Thank you! This works brilliantly and is perfect for now until the UNIQUE function roles out!

Comment: No problem at all Richard. I also cannot wait to give `UNIQUE` a try :) cheers

Answer (score 3):

Select all your data.

Then, in the options ribbon, tab DATA, look up for Remove Duplicates:

[image]

Click on Accept. You will get this output:

[image]

More info:

> **[Find and remove duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d)**